# JavaScript click and focus event order

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a span inside a div, the div has an `onfocus()` event, while the span has an `onclick()` like so:

```
<div id="divEl" tabindex="0">
  <span id="spanEl"></span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nyva4jrc/

When clicking on the span, the `div.focus` event fires first, despite the fact that, by my understanding, it should only fire after the click has bubbled up to the div.

Is there a a reason for this, and is the event firing order in this situation defined? Also is there any reference for the order in which dissimilar events fire?

Comment: do you realize that both the `focus()` and `click()` event are firing on input?

Comment: Yes, but they do different things. The span does not cover the entire div, it's possible to click outside of it.

Comment: fair enough, as long as you understand that, just know that the inside-out pattern of bubbling is consistent in jq delegated events, and thus 100% repeatable. i think jq even bubbles `onblur`... note that the html event attribs you show don't behave the same way as jq's `.on()`-based events.

Comment: But that's the thing, the outside `focus()` event is firing first, which seems counter to the bubbling model.

Comment: log the `event.target` and it should make more sense...

Comment: I've created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/382922ot/ - click on the (green) span, the focus event is definitely firing first, and firing on the div.

Comment: ok, i took a look at your fiddle and it's a bit different. i was talking more along the lines of overlapping events: https://jsfiddle.net/r6m3r7q8/

Comment: Right, that demonstrates that the `focus()` event fires before `click()` on a single element. What I'm wondering is why `focus()` seems to violate the event bubbling model. I've also reengineered my test not to use jQuery (you can see it in the edited main question), this behaviour is indeed native to the bubbling model.

Comment: w3 focus and blur don't bubble in the same way as something like a click does. there are bubbling equivalents, like `focusin` and `focusout`

Comment: Fair enough, but what I'm wondering is if there a defined order in which the two bubble? Does the entire focus bubbling occur before any of the clicking bubbling? And does it do so consistently across modern browsers?